# What ruby automation options (capybara, watir) will let me use Selenium 3?

Tags: ruby, selenium3

Selenium 3 came out in 2016.

Which ruby test frameworks have adopted it?

I want to use `contains` which is available in Selenium 3 for selecting elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the listed dependencies (as of 6/14/2017)

[capybara](https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/versions/2.14.2)

> selenium-webdriver < 4.0, >= 2.0

Except version 3.4.1 due to this [issue](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/2cce7eb4d337a00a9639db0c085d4eb199dce506).

```
s.add_development_dependency("selenium-webdriver", [">= 2.0", "< 4.0", "!=3.4.1"])
```

[watir](https://rubygems.org/gems/watir-webdriver)

> selenium-webdriver >= 2.46.2

Answer (score 0):

### As of 06/14/2017

#### capybara is still on Selenium 2

#### watir release 6.0 (Nov 9th 2016) has support for Selenium 3

Comment: I think capybara, since version 2.11.0 supports selenium 3 (https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/versions/2.14.2) - see the `selenium-webdriver` dependency is set to `< 4.0, >= 2.0`..

Comment: https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara says "At the moment, Capybara supports Selenium 2.0 (Webdriver)".  The dependency on the link your mention says `<4` and `>=2` so I'm still not sure as that could mean 2 or 3.  I don't see it in https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/History.md I'm not sure

Comment: It includes 3, `s.add_development_dependency("selenium-webdriver", [">= 2.0", "< 4.0", "!=3.4.1"])` as seen [here](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/commit/2cce7eb4d337a00a9639db0c085d4eb199dce506)

Comment: maybe add that to answer